# About taking a variable inside the loop and taking it ouside

Tags: java

Hello just a question is it possible to take a variable inside a for loop outside? Is there a way for the string removeLast to take its value outside?

Here is the example code.

```
for (char c : reversefirststring.toCharArray()) {
    int num = charToCode(c);
    String num2 = (num + "-");
    String removeLast = (num2);     
}
System.out.print(removeLast);
```

Comment: Yes, declare it *before* the loop.

Comment: Declare and initialize it before the loop. Otherwise it won't be definitely assigned after the loop, and you won't be able to use it.

Comment: (Not that a loop is obviously necessary here)

Answer (score 1):

Just move definition of this variable out of the loop `{}`. It's called visibility zone.

```java
String removeLast = null;

for (char c : reversefirststring.toCharArray()) {
    int num = charToCode(c);
    String num2 = (num + "-");
    removeLast = (num2);     
}

System.out.print(removeLast);
```